# Video not saving in DCIM folder

Tags: android, google-glass, mediarecorder, internal-storage

I'm trying save recording video:

```
File videoFile;
File sampleDir =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                     + File.separator + "DCIM/Camera/");
try
{ 
    videoFile = File.createTempFile("ibm", ".mp4", sampleDir);
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    Log.e(TAG,"sdcard access error");
    return;
}
Log.i(TAG,"name file: "+videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());

mMediaRecorder.prepare();
mMediaRecorder.start();
```

After call:

```
mMediaRecorder.stop();
mMediaRecorder.reset();     
mMediaRecorder.release();
```

In dcim folder my video file is out... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested permission to write to external storage? `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Another alternative is to use [Context#getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) instead, you should be able to use it without requesting permission to write to external storage. This is new in KitKat (Android 4.4, API level 19), which Google Glass is running.

Comment: Yes, i'm add all permission -

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are having trouble due to the new bug in the latest firmware version, please check http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=578 and see if the bug is relevant to you. In my case, I can see the files that are created but are empty.